# Average resistance of MOSFET output characteristics

Tags: mosfet, resistance

Suppose we calculate the resistance at two points in a MOSFET output characteristic.
For example: Vgs is at 5 V. At Vds = 5 V, Id = 10 μA and at Vds = 2.5V, Id = 9.3 μA.

To determine the equivalent resistor of the tansistor, what should I do?

Comment: \$\Delta V/\Delta I~ = ~ ESR=1/g_m\$ but at 5V it appears like 500k and at 2.5V appears like 269k so the average is 384k

Comment: (Ra + Rb)/2? But dV/dI must give the slope right? Slope being theresistance ?

Comment: the slope is the incremental resistance  often called ESR, like in diodes when they saturate.

Comment: in which region you want to know the resistance, linear or saturation?

Answer (score 1):

\$V_{GS}=5V\$, and is kept fixed for the following two measurements:

1. When \$V_{DS} = 5V\$, the resulting \$I_D=10\mu A\$
2. When \$V_{DS} = 2.5V\$, the resulting \$I_D=9.3\mu A\$

Calculate the equivalent resistance under those two conditions, with Ohm's law:

1. \$R_{DS} = \frac{V_{DS}}{I_D} = \frac{5}{10\times 10^{-6}} = 500k\Omega\$
2. \$R_{DS} = \frac{V_{DS}}{I_D} = \frac{2.5}{9.3\times 10^{-6}} = 270k\Omega\$

The graph of \$V_{DS}\$ vs. \$I_D\$, from these two data points may be a straight line (we'd need more data points to know if that's true; spoiler: it isn't).

The resistance is not "ohmic", conforming to the relationship \$R=\frac{V}{I}\$. If it was, the resistance values we calculated above would be equal, and the V-I graph would pass through the origin (it does not, see the graph below).

Perhaps you are referring to dynamic resistance, which would be the ratio of *change* in voltage \$\Delta V_{DS}\$ to *change* in current \$\Delta I_D\$. Even though the graph of \$V_{DS}\$ vs. \$I_D\$ isn't likely to be a straight line, let's pretend it is, and draw a line right through those two points:

[image]

The dynamic "equivalent resistance" will be the gradient of that line. You didn't need a graph to work that out:

$$ R = \frac{\Delta V_{DS}}{\Delta I_D} = \frac{V_{DS2}-V_{DS1}}{I_{D2}-I_{D1}} = \frac{5-2.5}{10\mu - 9.3\mu} = 3.57M\Omega $$

Answer (score 0):

Using the long-channel model, the slope of the output characteristic is

K/2 * W/L * Ve

where Ve is Vgs - Vt

For short-channel models, look at the plots of gm versus Vds, etc

Answer (score 0):

'Average Resistance' is not a well-formed parameter. Likely the OP means 'Output Impedance'. This is a useful value when the device is in saturation.

This would be Δ/Δ = (5-2.5)/(10μ-9.3μ) = 3.6 MΩ. This could be considered the 'average' over that VDS range.

However, at VGS = 5 V, and VDS = 2.5 V, the transistor is likely not in saturation (because VGD is > VTH likely), so the output impedance is not measured correctly, and changes significantly over the VDS = 2.5 ... 5.0 range. Likely measuring at VDS = 4.0 or 4.5 V would give a more useful value.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I look at the data sheet as I know the part will meet that specification from a reputable supplier and even exceed it but I do not know by how much each parameter will deviate from that number. One very important parameter you are missing is temperature, this has a big impact on the output resistance. These parameters will even vary from die to die on a single wafer. We measured the resistance by placing a load on it, measuring the current and voltage drop, from that we determined the resistance. To state the average resistance you need more information and need to also consider lot to lot tolerances.  Average is not a tested parameter.  Hopefully this helps you resolve your question.